# Found a PyPi Package for Opencv-contrib, but can't install using pip

Tags: opencv, pip, python-3, raspbian-stretch

I'm trying to install OpenCV for python with extra modules on my raspberry pi. The OpenCV website has a set of instructions that I have tried with different variations for the past several months. I have concluded over ~25 attempts that these will not work.
Since I'm only going to be using OpenCV in python, I have changed tactics to just 
using pip to install opencv with modules.

However when I try I get this:

[image: The error I receive]

Opencv-contrib-python is in the pip packages list, as well as on the PyPI website.
I have run 
`pip(3) install --upgrade pip`
as the PyPI page suggests.
If I link directly to the PyPI page download link, I receive this error.

[image: The next error I recieve]

This issue is only with the contrib modules.
`pip(3) install opencv-python` works.

How do I install the package successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opencv-contrib-python` contains pre-compiled binaries, which, by their nature, only work for a specific architecture. Pip only has builds for x86 and x86_64 (no ARM builds, which is what you'd need on a Pi).

You will need to  compile [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) yourself instead, since there aren't any available binaries for ARM processors. Be aware that since the Pi isn't very beefy, this will likely take a non-trivial amount of time ([this site](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/) claims 2.8 hours for the Pi 2 and 9.5 hours for the original B+, and this site [estimates](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/) about 1.5 hours for a Pi 3).

For instructions on compiling OpenCV, see: **[How to install OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 3 in Raspbian Jessie?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/69169/58316)**

Comment: Ah. That's what I feared. Unfortunately I've tried that guide and the cmake compilation always freezes at the end and fails, or it succeeds but without compiling the extra modules. At this point I feel like Sisyphus, but I suppose I'll just try again.

Comment: @Falcondance You could try [cross-compiling OpenCV](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/opencv/build/) (this involves you compiling on your normal PC, which should be significantly faster, but telling the compiler to compile for the Pi's architecture). That might help (see also [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/72089/58316)) but unfortunately I haven't tried it myself, so I can't comment on whether it'd even work. Good luck.