# Installing a specific version of pymongo using pip3

Tags: pip

Raspi/Linux noob here.

Due to compatibility issues with another program, I need to install an older version of pymongo. 3.5.1 to be more specific.

I have used pip3 for the pymongo install. So, based on advice I found online, I tried:

```
sudo pip3 install pymongo==3.5.1
```

But this gives the error message `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Or how to install a specific version of pymongo?

Comment: https://youtu.be/biihXKhxqXc Watch this video this might remove your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar issue to a [previous Pip question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/77310/58316) — the [pymongo package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo) has architecture specific builds for x86 and x86_64 processors only. There is no ARM package available, so Pip isn't able to find a package that is suitable for your Pi.

The Raspbian repositories [offer PyMongo 3.4.0](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3-pymongo), and you can install that with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pymongo
```

Otherwise, you will likely need to [download the sources](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/) and compile/setup the appropriate version yourself, it appears.

Comment: No problem, @SomeRandomFinn. Don't forget that you can accept this answer with the checkmark if you solved this problem — [that's our way of saying thanks](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: sorry it took ages to accept the answer! (Linux noob *and* Stackoverflow noob to boot!) Added for posterity: turns out you can also install a version "older than" some specific version. (How cool is that!!!??) With (e.g.): sudo pip3 install 'pymongo<3.6.0'